# Turtle file contains 0 triples

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, protege, fuseki

I want to upload turtle file into apache jena fuseki server. But when i upload , there is 0 triples uploaded

I have an ontology. I want to make some query on apache jena fuseki server. I upload the ontology file as turtle format. But there's 0 triples uploaded.

When i tried to upload with rdf format , there's triples uploaded as the picture below

[Upload ontology file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IErhw.png)

Is there something i miss? why when i upload ontology in turtle format it says 0 triples uploaded , but when i upload in rdf format , it says there's triples in it? How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use the file extension `.ttl`?

Comment: @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions is correct - upload via Fuseki UI considers file extension as indicator for syntax, and in your case it expects RDF/XML

Comment: The server log file will give more information.